# Can't get xml2js Builder example working

Tags: xml, json, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to use xml2js to parse apart xml from rest API return and then turn the modified JSON back into XML to send back. But I can't seem to get xml2js's default builder example from their [GitHub](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) to work. Any recommendation on what's wrong here or another node package to use to accomplish this?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');

var obj = { name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: 23};

var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
```

The Error I am getting back is:

```
var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/test.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: did you install xml2js via npm?

Comment: yes I did version ~0.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said on GitHub:

This is because the XML Builder hasn't been published to npm yet.
If you wish to use it, you should download the repo from GitHub and use it as such.
(don't forget to run `npm install` when doing so)

Comment: Thanks this was the issue, NPM does fight with the install a bit more when installing from your git repo but I got it to work. Can you update the README with a note aboutthis requirement where you have the example I don't see anything where you are explaining the builder function.

Answer (score 0):

Agree, would be helpful if that was in the notes as wasted a little bit of time figuring out what was wrong and ended up here.

To install via NPM from master just use

npm install https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/archive/master.tar.gz

Comment: He just updated the NPM package so hopefully this won't be an issue any longer as it should now be included.